# How to set keyboard layout and keep configuration?

Tags: keyboard-layout, i3, setxkbmap

I changed from gnome to i3wm and now everytime I log in to my computer the keyboard layout is set to english (my keyboard is spanish).

I was able to change it with this command but just for the current session.

```
setxkbmap -layout latam
```

I tried adding this configuration to `~/.zsh_profile` and `~/.profile` but it didn't work.

Comment: Try adding it to `~/.xsession`.  The trick is in telling your display manager to read that file.

Comment: Tried it with the same results